# SSH Hangs. error: openpty: No such file or directory error: session_pty_req: session 0 alloc failed

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-14.04

One of our Ubuntu 14.04 production servers stopped accepting SSH connections. When we try to login we get the SSH Banner text, but then it just hangs. If we login using the management console, we can see the following error messages in /var/log/auth.log

```
Oct  4 17:37:20 servername sshd[10975]: error: Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
Oct  4 17:37:21 servername sshd[10975]: Accepted publickey for username from 10.0.0.1 port 57230 ssh2: RSA xx:xx:xx:xx
Oct  4 17:37:21 servername sshd[10975]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user username by (uid=0)
Oct  4 17:37:25 servername sshd[10975]: error: openpty: No such file or directory
Oct  4 17:37:25 servername sshd[6869]: error: session_pty_req: session 0 alloc failed
```

Using `cat /proc/mounts| grep devpts; ls -hal /dev/{pts,ptmx}` I can verify it exists and has the correct permissions, and that there aren't any disk/inode issues:

```
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,mode=600,ptmxmode=000 0 0

crw-rw-rw- 1 root tty  5, 2 Oct  4 17:01 /dev/ptmx

/dev/pts:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root       0 Aug 14 00:52 .
drwxr-xr-x 17 root root    4.3K Oct  4 17:01 ..
crw--w----  1 root tty  136, 18 Oct  4 17:41 18
crw--w----  1 root tty  136, 24 Oct  1 13:57 24
crw--w----  1 root tty  136,  3 Oct  4 17:39 3
crw--w----  1 root tty  136, 30 Oct  4 11:29 30
c---------  1 root root   5,  2 Aug 14 00:52 ptmx

df -h
    Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
    udev            252G  4.0K  252G   1% /dev
    tmpfs            51G   53M   51G   1% /run
    /dev/sdi2       220G   13G  197G   6% /
    none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
    none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
    none            252G   12K  252G   1% /run/shm
    none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
    /dev/sdi1        75M   512   75M   1% /boot/efi
    /dev/md1        3.5T  282G  3.0T   9% /ssd

df -hi
    Filesystem     Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
    udev              63M   526   63M    1% /dev
    tmpfs             63M   725   63M    1% /run
    /dev/sdi2         14M  171K   14M    2% /
    none              63M     2   63M    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
    none              63M     1   63M    1% /run/lock
    none              63M     4   63M    1% /run/shm
    none              63M     4   63M    1% /run/user
    /dev/sdi1           0     0     0     - /boot/efi
    /dev/md1         224M    46  224M    1% /ssd
```

I also verified the sshd_config matches another server and have restarted the ssh service. I believe the devpty system is mounted on startup, but is there any way to resolve the issue without restarting the server?

I see https://access.redhat.com/solutions/67972 has a unverified solution for this issue on RedHat, but I don't have access to a RedHat Subscription.

Answer (score 1):

I found I could get a non-tty based ssh session to work using:

```
$ ssh username@servername /bin/bash -i

bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device
bash: no job control in this shell
username@servername:~$
```

I think in this case the ioctl error is expected, because I am starting an interactive session on something that doesn't have a tty. Lots of things have issues in this session (TERM env var isn't even set), but I was able to do some basic troubleshooting and found this:

```
#View a process list with parent process details
ps -axfo pid,uname,cmd | grep badservice | wc -l
27917
```

Basically we found one of our services had over 27900 processes running under their username, when we compared this with the good server

```
$ salt 'server*' cmd.run 'ps -aux | grep badservice | wc -l'
server.good:
    3
server.bad:
    27918
```

Likely this was causing some sort of resource exhaustion related to ptys. The bad service was stopped, and I killed any remaining processes for that user using `sudo kill -u badservice`. After which, SSH started working as expected again!

Comment: This solved my problem of openpty ssh username@servername /bin/bash -i

Answer (score 0):

I checked another server that was working, and noticed the mount options were a bit different:

```
Bad Server:  devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,mode=600,ptmxmode=000 0 0
Good Server: devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000 0 0
```

I tried the following which was able to change the mount permissions to match the good server:

```
sudo mount -o remount /dev/pts
sudo grep devpts /proc/mounts

devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000 0 0
```

But I still get the same errors trying to connect (even after restarting ssh again).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was caused by me mounting /dev with the option `--rbind` into a directory of another mashine, I wanted to `chroot` into.

```
mkdir -p /media/snapshot/
mkdir -p /media/test/
mount /dev/vg0/snapshot /media/snapshot/
mount /dev/vg0/test /media/test/
mount -t proc none /media/test/proc
mount --rbind /dev /media/test/dev
mount -t sysfs sysfs /media/test/sys
chroot /media/test/ /bin/bash
exit
```

Those folders were mounted:

```
udev on /media/test/dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=346156k,nr_inodes=86539,mode=755)
devpts on /media/test/dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /media/test/dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
mqueue on /media/test/dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
```

When unmounting the volume, (which stated that it was still used) with the option `-l` the other mount points inside /dev were unmounted too:

```
umount -l /media/test
ll /dev/pts
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   40 Mai 13 07:06 .
drwxr-xr-x 18 root root 4,1K Mai 13 07:07 ..
```

## Workaround:

reboot the server and all /dev mounts are recreated

## Solution:

with `--bind` instead of `--rbind` the problem does not occur:

```
mount --bind /dev /media/test/dev
```